# julia1.0.2では内積がつかえないのですか？

Tags: julia

ネットにはJuliaの内積はdot(A,B)を使えみたいなことが書いてあります。
ここで、以下の配列をdot使うと

```
n=3
psi = zeros(Float32,n,n,n,6)
psi[1,1,1,:] = [1/sqrt(2),1,1,1,1,1]
psi[1,1,1,:].*psi[1,1,1,:]
dot(psi[1,1,1,:],psi[1,1,1,:])
```

と計算してみると

```
UndefVarError: dot not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[46]:6
```

とでてしまいます。このバージョンにはないのでしょうか？

Comment: [Linear Algebra · The Julia Language](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html) の冒頭に、`... useful linear algebra operations which can be loaded with using LinearAlgebra.` と書かれていますので、`using LinearAlgebra` としてから実行すると良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほどありがとうございます！

Comment: @metropolis さん、回答としてご投稿頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

[Linear Algebra · The Julia Language](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/index.html) の冒頭に

> ... useful linear algebra operations which can be loaded with using LinearAlgebra.

と書かれていますので、`using LinearAlgebra` としてから実行すると良いのではないでしょうか。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51045/julia1-0-2%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e5%86%85%e7%a9%8d%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8b%e3%81%88%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b#comment53267_51045) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*